# Remove trailing data from Django timesince

Tags: python, django, datetime

Is there a way to remove the trailing data from the django `timesince` filter?

I would like to only display days, weeks months or years without any trailing information. e.g weeks + days -> weeks, months + weeks -> months, years + months -> years, etc.

Additionally, if the date is less than one day, it should display the hours. e.g. 1 hour ago, 4 hours ago, etc.

Currently I have a datetime object and am using the filter like this:

```
{{ my_date_time|timesince}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your own template tag and use it to modify the output of `timesince` to be anything you like. Here's an example just to get you started:

```
def custom_timesince(value):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    # can add some error checking if you want
    diff = now - value
    if diff < timedelta(days=1):
        return "recently" # or w/e you wanted with the hours

    # remove trailing information from timesince    
    return timesince(value).split(", ")[0]
```

possibly helpful: [docs on using such custom tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/)

Comment: The only thing I want to add to this is that since I'm passing in a datetime object, `return timesince(value).split(", ")[0]` is enough to cover all my cases. Thanks!