# Remove trailing data from django timesince -- template equivalent

Tags: python, django, datetime

What is the Django template equivalent to this?:

```
timesince(value).split(", ")[0]
```

I have a use case where I can't using templatetags. In my templatetag, I would do something like this:

```
@register.filter
def custom_timesince(value):
    return timesince(value).split(", ")[0]
```

How would I go about doing this in my Django HTML template without using a templatetag? My variable in the django template is:

```
{{datetime_obj}}
```

**Edit:**
If possible I'd like to replicate the functionality in:
[Remove trailing data from Django timesince](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43126257/remove-trailing-data-from-django-timesince)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Instead of template tag, use the [`timesince`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#timesince) template filter. Like this:

   ```
   {{ datetime_obj|timesince:comparison_date }}
   ```

   Note, that `comparison_date` is optional.
2. You can also use the [`naturaltime`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/humanize/#naturalday) template filter of the `humanize` built-in lib. Like this:

   ```
   {{ datetime_obj|naturaltime }}
   ```

   If you choose the latter, don't forget to add `django.contrib.humanize` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting and also put `{% load humanize %}` at the top of your template where you want to use `naturaltime`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. If possible, I would like to replicate the functionality in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43126257/remove-trailing-data-from-django-timesince

Comment: The best and more readable way of doing this, is writing your own [template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters), just as the answer in the question you posted. Note, it's not a template tag. It's a template filter. It's nothing more than a function which you can reuse anywhere.